# Push to an array and keep the array n items long

Tags: javascript

How do I push an object to an array, then when the array becomes, say, 100 items in size, remove the first one and push again, and so on?

It could be a method, like `arr.push('log item', 100)`
How do I implement it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
if(arr.length === 100)
        arr.shift(); 
arr.push(VAL);
```

A method more like the OP's original request, replacing the `push()` with a new one with the option of limiting the size of the array

```
Array.prototype.originalPush = Array.prototype.push;
Array.prototype.push = function(val,limit)
{
    if(limit && this.length == limit)
        this.shift();
    this.originalPush(val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simpy [shift](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp) when you go over fixed length:

```js
Array.prototype.push_maxlength = function(item, length) {
  this.push(item);
  if (this.length > length) {
    this.shift();
  }
}

var a = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  a.push_maxlength(i, 5);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`myArray.slice(1)` will return an array without the first item. So something along the lines of :

```
myArray.push(myNewData);
if (myArray.length > 100) {
  myArray = myArray.slice(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check length!

```
function addTo100(array, newItem){
    if (array.length == 100){
        array.shift();
    }
    array.push(newItem);
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pushMax(arr, val, maxLength) {
    arr.push(val);

    if (arr.length > maxLength) {
        array.shift();
    }
}

pushMax(arr, 'log item', 100);
```